# Why should I care about proving a polynomial to be irreducible?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, motivation

Are there any number theoretic/combinatorial/other applications of proving that a polynomial is irreducible over integers/any other field ?(But integers are preferred)

Comment: The fact $x^2 \pm p$ is not irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p,i)$ (with $\zeta_p = e^{2i \pi /p}$) implies the [quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_quadratic_reciprocity#Proof_using_Quadratic_Gauss_Sums)

Comment: @reuns Brilliant motivating example ! You should consider adding it as an example in the answer. (BTW, I know what quadratic reciprocity is, but what does Q(zeta_p, i) mean ?)

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is the smallest field containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\alpha$. If $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ then you can see it as a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$. $\alpha$ can also be a free variable (field of rational functions), or an abstract algebraic number ie. "the root of a certain irreducible polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$". In that case $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is isomorphic to [$\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f(x))$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_extension)).

Answer (score 1):

A basic use of this concept: a polynomial $p(x)$ is irreducible over a field $F$ if and only if $F[x]/p(x)$ is a field.

More generally, suppose you want to understand the isomorphism class of the quotient $F[x]/p(x)$ for an arbitrary polynomial $p(x)$. This boils down to understanding the prime factorization of $p(x)$; say it is

$$p(x) = \prod_i p_i(x)^{m_i}$$

where the $p_i$ are irreducible. Then

$$F[x]/p(x) \cong \prod_i F[x]/p_i(x)^{m_i}$$

by the Chinese remainder theorem, where $F[x]/p_i(x)^{m_i}$ is an artinian [local ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_ring) with residue field $F[x]/p_i(x)$. Geometrically we are trying to understand the "scheme of zeroes" $\text{Spec } \mathbb{F}[x]/p(x)$ of $p(x)$, and the theorem above tells us that this scheme consists topologically of a finite set of ("fat") points, one for each irreducible factor of $p(x)$.

Irreducibility is a very fundamental concept, and if you keep studying abstract algebra and/or number theory you'll keep running into it sooner or later. There's no need to be in any particular hurry, though; either you'll run into it or you won't.

Comment: @Alex: well, your question was extremely terse, and that's a pretty different and much more specific question from the question in your title. I don't know any examples of such problems off the top of my head.

Comment: Ask Evan Chen, maybe?

Comment: Yep, that's him.